# Context menu shows up behind my main form

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a context menu that I declare nested within some other xaml as follows:

```xml
<ContextMenu Name="cm2">
    <ContextMenu.BitmapEffect>
    <OuterGlowBitmapEffect />
    </ContextMenu.BitmapEffect>
    <MenuItem Header="Chat" Click="btnChat_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Send Email" Click="btnEmail_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Edit Information" Click="btnEdit_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Add New Contact" Click="btnAddNewContact_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

This is all good and well like 99% of the time in `Windows 7, Vista and XP`.  However, I have two people using my software who when they right click in the area where this `context menu` originates, the context menu shows up behind the main form.  This only happens to people using XP, but only a small fraction of the `XP users`.

The main windows in which this context menu lives is defined as:

```xml
<Window x:Class="Application.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Application" mc:Ignorable="d" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Application.Properties"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" Topmost="False" 
    WindowStyle="None" Icon="/Application;component/Images/image.png" 
    Background="{x:Null}" AllowsTransparency="True" Foreground="White" 
    Width="682" Height="389" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Closing="OnClose" StateChanged="OnStateChanged" IsVisibleChanged="OnIsVisibleChanged" MinWidth="650" MinHeight="300">
```

I inherited this project and an not anything close to an expert on Wpf, so this could be something really simple that I am overlooking.

Comment: i don t have answer but maybe what changes beetween xp working / not working might be the theme (classic / xp) it changes quite some things. Can you set panel.Zindex in your window ??

Comment: can you write a compiler directive that checks the version of the OS, if XP write some sort of bringtofront or hide all other windows..??

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the ContextMenuService.Placement property?